# Laravel Storage Multiple Value Json Format

Tags: php, arrays, json, laravel, mariadb

I am trying to throw SQL information in JSON format from the form. I saved the information in the SQL area, but it saves it in the form of SQL escape. When I shoot with API, I can't use it as I want. The codes are as follows. I wonder where I am making mistakes, but I could not find a solution.

Migrate for workers column

```
$table->text('workers')->nullable();
```

**Model** I wrote that the workers' column in the table is in an array format

```
protected $casts = [
        'workers' => 'array',
    ];
```

**Blade or view**  It is necessary to save ***multiple*** data here such as name, id

```
<select class="js-example-basic-multiple searchselect form-control show-tick" name="workers[]" multiple="multiple">
     @foreach ($personels as $personel)
<option value='{"spid":{{ $personel->id }},"spsicil":{{ $personel->sicil_no }},"spname":"{{ $personel->name }}"}'>{{ $personel->name }}</option>
     @endforeach
</select>
```

Controller File

```
 $workers = implode(',', $request->workers);
 $new = "[".$workers."]";
        $data = new Zimmet();
        $data->name = $request->name;
        $data->sicil_no = $request->sicil_no;
        $data->proje_id = $request->proje_id;
        $data->workers = $new;
        $data->save();
```

I got used to converting the incoming data to array format, but I'm not sure of the correct one.

It records the workers column in the table as follows.

```
"[
{\"spid\":1,\"spsicil\":35678909,\"spname\":\"Mike\"},
{\"spid\":5,\"spsicil\":3,\"spname\":\"Jhon\"},
{\"spid\":4,\"spsicil\":44,\"spname\":\"Erica\"}
]"
```

Multiple Value How do I correctly add to the database in array or json format.

Thank you for your advice and help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue over here is, the string is JSONified twice.

I would suggest you remove the following lines from your code

```
$workers = implode(',', $request->workers);
$new = "[".$workers."]";
```

Updated code should be:

```
    $data = new Zimmet();
    $data->name = $request->name;
    $data->sicil_no = $request->sicil_no;
    $data->proje_id = $request->proje_id;
    $data->workers = $request->workers;
    $data->save();
```

Explanation:

```
protected $casts = [
    'workers' => 'array',
];
```

Takes care of Serialization and Deserialization of Array to JSON while storing into the Database and fetching from Database.

I hope, this will help you.

Best.

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-mutators#array-and-json-casting